# Does enabling category and product flat data will affect performance in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, category, performance, flat-catalog

I have huge doubt in flat data feature in Magneto 2.

If I enable product and category flat data in Magento 2.

Will it affect the website performance heavily ?

Answer (score 3):

it will not help in a performance boost in the latest version with Magento plus Magento no longer recommend use flat catalog option for more info

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html